# Python list updaitng even when condition evaluates to False

Tags: python, control-flow

Why is the longest_palindrome variable updated when the isPalindrome() function evaluates to False? The if/else condition is not behaving as I would expect.

```
def palindromeCutting(s):
    if s == "":
        return ""

    letters = list(s)

    while len(letters) > 0:
        tmp = []
        longest_palindrome = []
    
        for i in range(len(letters)):
            tmp.append(letters[i])

            if isPalindrome(tmp):
                print("updating longest with tmp")
                longest_palindrome = tmp
            print("longest_palindrome:",longest_palindrome)

        if len(longest_palindrome) > 1:
            l = len(longest_palindrome)
            letters = letters[l:]
        else:
            return "".join(letters)

def isPalindrome(arr):
    left, right = 0, len(arr) - 1

    while left <= right:
        if arr[left] != arr[right]:
            return False
        left += 1
        right -= 1

    return True
```

The output for this when run with s = "aaacodedoc" is:

```
longest_palindrome: ['a']
longest_palindrome: ['a', 'a']
longest_palindrome: ['a', 'a', 'a']
longest_palindrome: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'c']
longest_palindrome: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'o']
longest_palindrome: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'o', 'd']
longest_palindrome: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'o', 'd', 'e']
longest_palindrome: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'o', 'd', 'e', 'd']
longest_palindrome: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'o', 'd', 'e', 'd', 'o']
longest_palindrome: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'o', 'd', 'e', 'd', 'o', 'c']
```

Comment: You could replace the definition of isPalindrom by this much shorter one : `def isPalindrom(arr): return arr == arr[::-1]` (returns array == reverse of array)

Comment: Thanks, but I still can't see why the variable is updated when the condition evaluates to False. Do you have any idea why that is?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting `longest_palindrom` to `tmp`. From that point on, `tmp` and `longest_palindrom` are pointing to the same object. Whenever `tmp` is modified, the modification is reflected on `longest_palindrom`, and vice-versa.

To avoid that, you could instead set `longest_palindrom` to a *copy* of `tmp`, replacing the line

```
longest_palindrom = tmp
```

by

```
longest_palindrom = tmp[:]
```

which sets longest_palindrom to a *new* list containing the elements of `tmp`.

If you want a more in-depth explanation of list aliasing, the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-can-i-prevent-it) explain it very well.

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful! I was forgetting that I needed to make a copy.

Answer (score 1):

you are referencing tmp with longest_palindrome.
So they both point to the same object.

After 3rd iteration tmp object is still growing so the longest_palindrome does also.

> longest_palindrome = tmp

You can try by copying / creating new object with the same content:

> longest_palindrome = tmp[:]

Comment: Thank you! I forgot that I needed to make a copy!